# Remark 4.1.4 in Riehl's, *Category Theory in Context*

Tags: category-theory

[image]

I'm having trouble proving the statement in Remark 4.1.4, i.e using $k\circ f=g\circ Fh\iff Gk\circ f^\sharp=g^\sharp\circ h$ to prove $Gk\circ f^\sharp =(k\circ f)^\sharp,\; g^\sharp \circ h=(g\circ Fh)^\sharp$. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The point is very simple, if the square with say $F$ commutes, you apply $G$ on the whole diagram and then use the naturality to get rid of the $GFc$ and $GFc'$ and replace them by $c$ and $c'$. Have you tried that? What happened? (Did you see the units and counits appear?) I would draw the thing in diagrams but sadly I don't know how to implement this in MathJax (is it even possible? I see you did this with pictures).

If you try doing this with equations, the statement that the first diagram commutes is that $g \circ Fh = k \circ f$, and the naturality statement says that if the natural isomorphism is denoted by $\varphi_{c,d} : \mathrm{Hom}(Fc,d) \to \mathrm{Hom}(c,Gd)$, then for any morphisms $\psi : Fc \to d$, $\alpha_c : c'' \to c$ and $\alpha_d : d \to d''$, we have 
$$
\varphi_{c'',d''}(\alpha_d \circ \psi \circ F \alpha_c) = G \alpha_d \circ \varphi_{c,d}(\psi) \circ \alpha_c. 
$$
Applying $\varphi_{c,d'}$ to $g \circ Fh = k \circ f$ (choose the appropriate $c,c'',d,d''$ and morphisms, and plug in the above to get the first and third equality), we get 
$$
 Gk \circ \varphi_{c',d}(f) = \varphi_{c,d'}(k \circ f) = \varphi_{c,d'}(g \circ Fh) = \varphi_{c',d}(g) \circ h.
$$
I am guessing your $^{\sharp}$ notation refers to the natural isomorphism, so we are done.

(The other direction is completely symmetric.)

Added : to prove what you actually wanted to show, if you pick $h$ to be the identity, then the first and second square become triangles ; the fact that the first triangle commutes implies that the second triangle commutes translates to 
$$
\varphi_{c,d'}(k \circ f) = \varphi_{c,d'}(g) = Gk \circ \varphi_{c,d}(f),
$$
which is exactly what you wanted to prove. Taking $k$ to be the identity instead, you get
$$
\varphi_{c,d'}^{-1}(g^{\sharp} \circ h) = \varphi_{c,d'}^{-1}(f^{\sharp}) = \varphi_{c,d'}^{-1}(g^{\sharp}) \circ Fh = g \circ Fh,
$$
which is again exactly what you wanted to show.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Doesn't this assume one of the equations in $k\circ f=g\circ Fh\iff Gk\circ f^\sharp=g^\sharp\circ h$ actually holds? As I understand the remark, naturality should follow from their equivalence, without assuming either holds.

Comment: @Exterior : Sorry, I guess I proved Lemma 4.1.2 in my answer, so I did not indeed prove the converse as you requested. Don't ask me why I did that, I don't know. As this is category theory, there was only one obvious thing to do, which is to pick some morphism to be the identity. See my added comment in my answer.

Comment: ah! So simple! Thanks

Comment: Actually, I still think I don't understand a logical subtlety. How does the fact [first triangle commutes implies second triangle commutes] actually translate to the equality you mentioned? I don't understand this. It only seems to hold if you *assume* one of the triangles actually does commute and then use the implication, but as I understand, you need not assume this.

Comment: @Exterior : if you let $Fc \overset{ f}{\to} d \overset{k}{\to} d'$ and denote their composition by $g$, then $g = k \circ f$, so the induced triangle commutes. That is what I'm using. Such a triangle will not commute in general, but the one that commutes will commute! (...) When you want to show that $Gk \circ f^{\sharp} = (k \circ f)^{\sharp}$, the triangle with $k, f$ and $k \circ f$ does commute.

Answer (score 3):

This might get you started:

We want to show
$$\text{Naturality of isomorphisms} \color{red}{\iff} \left( \text{first square commutes} \color{blue}{\iff} \text{second square commutes} \right).$$

($\color{red}{\implies}$) (Only showing the $\color{red}\implies$ direction for now)

($\color{blue}{\implies}$) Suppose $k \circ f = g \circ Hf$. Then $(k \circ f)^\sharp = (g \circ Hf)^\sharp$. The former is $Gk \circ f^\sharp$ and the latter is $g^\sharp \circ h$. (To show this, draw squares for the naturality of the bijections in the first variable and in the second variable. Put $g$ in the first diagram and $f$ in the second, and see where they go. Remember that the bijections we're talking about are $l \mapsto l^\sharp$)

($\color{blue}{\impliedby}$) Similar.

Comment: Sorry about that edit, your coloration system is technically clear but I read it a bit fast... got confused! +1

Comment: I am asking about the converse implication. Thanks though :)

Comment: @exterior Did you get it yet? If you like I can fill out the converse.

Comment: @EricAuld It'd be great to see a proof of the converse, thanks!

Comment: @exterior Looks like Patrick got to it first. Let me know if that doesn't clear it up.

Comment: @EricAuld thank you! I wrote a comment on Patrick's answer explaining what I still don't understand.

Comment: @exterior Did Patrick's latest comment solve it for you?

Comment: @EricAuld yes, thank you!